# Java ArrayList serialization through ObjectOutputStream's writeObject method won't work

Tags: java, file, arraylist, serialization, io

I have a method of a "command" class that should save an ArrayList to file, but it saves garbage.
The method takes an ArrayList containing objects of a class (Beer) that implements Serializable (having only the "implements Serializable" keywords after the class name with no method implementations). It looks like this:

```
public class Save implements Command {
    public void execute(ArrayList<Beer> beers, String cmd []) {
    if(cmd[0].equals("save")) {


        File file = new File(cmd[1]);
        try
        {
           FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
           ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
           out.writeObject(beers);
           out.close();
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

for the list having beers with the following attributes:

```
[beername] [type] [strength]

heineken idk 5.3

pilsner idk 4.2
```

this is what's in the file:

¬í sr java.util.ArrayListxŇ™Çať I sizexp   w   sr beeregister.BeerřmRÁđ€ó F strengthL namet Ljava/lang/String;L styleq ~ xp@©™št heinekent idksq ~ @†fft pilsnert idkx

I have a load method too the same style, and it doesn't read the garbage above back to an ArrayList.

```
public class Load implements Command {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void execute(ArrayList<Beer> beers, String cmd[]) {
    if(cmd[0].equals("load")) {
        File file = new File(cmd[1]);
        try {
            FileInputStream fin= new FileInputStream (file);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
            beers = (ArrayList<Beer>)ois.readObject();
            fin.close();
        }
        catch(IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

How should I modify this code to make it save only the attributes into text file and load them back correctly? I'd like to stick to ObjectOutputStream's readObject and writeObject method.
Thanks

Comment: what do you get in the beers ArrayList after reading the file? The file is binary so don't expect to be able to read it via plain text.

Comment: also after writing the file do fileOut.close();

Comment: Post the error message(s) you receive.  "doesn't read the garbage above back to an ArrayList" is a useless problem description.  **What** happens?  "It doesn't work" provides zero information.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing ArrayList object as a parameter to load method you should create the new arraylist inside the load method and read the serialized file to the list and return it at the end of the method.

```
 public ArrayList<Beer> execute( String cmd[]) {
    ...

    return ((ArrayList<Beer>) ois.readObject());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem is rather the design of your Load.execute method than the read/write-process itself since the latter
works. But with your current design the loaded data get lost. You have to change your Load.execute method as follows.

Either change the signature of your method, declare an List-parameter inside your method, fill it as you already 
do and return it:

```
public class Load implements Command {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Beer> execute(String cmd[]) {
        List<Beer> beers = null;
        if(cmd[0].equals("load")) {
            ...
        }
        return beers;
    }
}
```

or fill the passed list using the addAll-method instead an assignment (because the latter does not fill the passed list):

```
public class Load implements Command {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void execute(ArrayList<Beer> beers, String cmd[]) {
        ...
        beers.addAll((ArrayList<Beer>) ois.readObject());
        ...
    }
}
```